# About UUID and generators in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I'm thinking to use UUID as PK for all tables into my new PostgreSQL database, for such a goal I will be using `uuid_generate_v5` and `uuid_ns_dns` or `uuid_ns_url` functions, but I have some doubts:

- is there any problems using UUIDs only in a database (i.e. performance)?
- is there any pros and cons respect to use `uuid_generate_v4`?
- When to use `uuid_ns_dns` or `uuid_ns_url`? (I haven't found info about it)
- can `name` parameter for `uuid_generate_v5` function be any string (even an empty string) or it depends on `namespace` parameter? Examples, please.

Comment: I don't know enough specific knowledge to answer your other questions so I'll refrain from posting and answer, but regarding your first question, `UUID` makes for a somewhat poorer data type to index on (particularly **B-Tree** indexes) as opposed to an `INT` or `BIGINT` because of their larger size and their potential for higher fragmentation. So yes `UUID` will be less performant than an `INT` or `BIGINT` data type for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

- There are no problems, but the performance will be somewhat worse than using a sequence generated `bigint` primary key, because adding one to an integer number has to perform better than anything more complicated. Also, a `uuid` takes twice the storage space (16 bytes).

  You should benchmark if that makes a noticeable difference for you.
- Apart from the performance impact, it makes no difference.
- It does not matter, they just return different constants.
- The `name` parameter can be any string. That function is `IMMUTABLE`, so you have to make sure that you use different names if you want different UUIDs.

Use UUIDs if you need to generate artificial primary keys in a decentralized fashion, for example in the application code or in different database if you use sharding. If the primary keys are generated in a single database, use a sequence.